# Estimating volatility of 15 stock market indices: univariate vs. multivariate models

Tags: arima, multivariate-analysis, garch

I am working with R and with financial series of 15 stock market indices with a weekly frequency.

I want to obtain the estimated volatility since it is the input I need to perform a volatility spillovers study.

Should I use an ARIMA model for each series to model the mean of each series or do I have to use a multivariate model?

After that, the doubt is the same, to obtain the estimated volatility, do you think I should apply a GARCH to each series or I can use a multivariate GARCH like DCC-GARCH?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Using a multivariate or an univariate depend on the fact that there could exist a certain dependency on your financial serie. I propose you do compute like a correlation matrix and see if there is a strong correlation. If there is no correlation, you can use a univariate for each serie (but you suppose that the dependency in only linear). If there is a strong correlation between some series and no correction with other serie the you can split your set of variable and do many multivariate models.

Comment: What you describe is a two-step procedure: (1) use some volatility model to obtain estimates of conditional variance and then (2) use some other model such as VAR to model the relationships (namely, spillovers) between them. Some authors do that, but I have always found this a bit weird. A more coherent approach might be to consider a single model for both purposes. The challenge with that is, however, that there are not so many multivariate GARCH models that facilitate volatility spillovers. E.g. DCC is not one of them... Perhaps GO-GARCH? I do not remember the details well enough to be sure.